# Angular 2 : System.import() : Not working with full path

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I am using below two different code to import a file runtime, one of them is working fine while other one throw error.

**Working:**

```
 System.import('../../FileName.ts').then(classObj => {          
        console.log(classObj);            
 });
```

**Not Working:**

```
 System.import('App/Models/FileName.ts').then(classObj => {          
        console.log(classObj);            
 });
```

It throw below error :

> Can not find module 'App/Models/FileName.ts'

**File Structure** in which code is written and i also trying to import file from same structure:

(1) Code : ActivityModel.ts
(2) Importing : ApplicationModel.ts

[image]

Any one can help me to resolve above full path consideration issue.

Comment: Seems like your FileName.ts is outside 2 folder so absolute path(App/Models/FileName.ts) won't work. you need to provide relative path (../../FileName.ts).

Comment: I know that, but in dynamic that not predefined file path, it can be any file from any folder, so i have full path.

Comment: can you try `'./App/Models/FileName'`

Comment: same issue. not working

Comment: @SandipPatel Did you set the `baseURL` config property of SystemJS?

Comment: @Dinistro: I haven't change any in SystemJs, can you please tell me in which file and where i have to change? because the main system.js file is minified

Comment: @SandipPatel The config would be somewhere in your code, not in the `system.js` file. Now, that I think of it, this seems not to be a baseUrl problem.

Comment: @SandipPatel Can you provide your file structure and tell us in which file you try to import the other?

Comment: I have updated the structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have latest version of webpack installed.Then you can try with following changes :

In `webpack.config.js` file change the following piece of code,

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', 'css'],
        "modules": [
            "./node_modules",
            "content"
        ]
    },
```

**And**

```
 output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/',
        }
```

In `.ts` file change,

```
System.import('horizontal/models/FileName.ts').then(classObj => {          
        console.log(classObj);            
 });
```

- The `resolver` is used to load files relative to the app root and by
  resolving `content` folder in `webpack.config.js`, file within that
  folder can be accessed by absolute path as shown above.

  (Now,path like `content/horizontal/models/FileName.ts` won't work)
- The bundle file of `FileName.ts` will be created in `dist` folder and
  will be loaded in the browser dynamically.Webpack will throw an error
  in the browser, that it `cannot load chunk 0` or something. This is
  because, it tries to load the other files relative to the your HTML
  file and not relative to the first JavaScript file you loaded via the
  script tag.

  To migrate this, you have to add a `publicPath` to your Webpack
  config.

Hope,It wil help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tsconfig

```
"baseUrl": "."
```

Replace the "." with a path that describes where to find the base folder for your imports. In my case, tsconfig was in the same folder as my app folder, so I simply set it to "."

Comment: No luck, still same issue